# Quickly *copy* the git url for an active IntelliJ project

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

When I created my project I used VCS -> Checkout from Version Control -> Git...

And I entered a url in the form:

```
https://me@my.git.server/scm/project/myrepo.git
```

Now that I am working in intellij, what is the quickest way to find this url once again?

I had a look in the Version Control tab and the Version Control popoup and couldn't see it easily.

*Additional requirement:*

I need to be able to copy the url to paste someplace else

Comment: Can't you use the terminal inside Intellij and create an alias which would copy the result of `git remote show origin` to clipboard? xsel does that for linux.

Answer (score 1):

From the menu bar click VCS->Git->Pull, and you will see the remote url in the dialog window.

Update:
If you need to be able to copy the url, you can run `git remote -v` or `git remote show origin` in IntelliJ's terminal. By default, you can toggle to the terminal window by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: I need to be able to copy the url. That feature can display it to me, but it wont allow copy. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you can just do it without IntelliJ ? Just go to your ".git" folder and you will see your URL in the "config" file (that way you can copy it)